# my carousel doesn't autoplay when my page loads

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, carousel, autoplay

Here is the code for my carousel, at one point it did star but suddenly it didn't, sometimes when i choose the menu option to go to my portfolio it does start but that's rare, it's there anything wrong with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main-slider').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    });
});


$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.panel-group').children().each(function(){
    $(this).find('>.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
     });

    $(this).closest('.panel-heading').toggleClass('active');
});


$(document).ready(function () {
new WOW().init();

$(window).load(function(){'use strict';
    var $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
    var $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
    $portfolio.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.portfolio-item',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });

    $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
        $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
});

var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),

        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});


$('.gototop').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: from the code you've pasted it looks like you have missed off a `});` at the end - you have a `$(document).ready` function opened before the wow.init but never closed.  Also does your console have any errors?

Comment: don't know, i didn't wrote the code, but anyways i just created one from scrath and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hei just go to your html file where your slider n find this code :

```
<div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt">
```

replace this code with

```
<div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt" data-ride="carousel">
```

Comment: <div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt" > replace with 
<div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt" data-ride="carousel">